# SUMIFS w/ multiple Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Base on the Emp ID and the Pay End date I'm looking to sum up the Total Earnings and if it is equal to or higher than the WC Cap in the exposure column I'd like to return the WC Cap value. If it's less than the WC Cap I'd like to return the SUM of the total earnings for the matching Emp ID and Pay End date in the exposure column.

Sample Data:

```
 Pay End     Emp ID   Total Earnings   WC (Cap)
 04/01/2014  CIA77    $1,858.80        $1,212.98 
 04/01/2014  COL23    $1,375.73        $1,212.98 
 04/01/2014  COM64      $285.20        $1,212.98 
 04/01/2014  COR71    $2,821.72        $1,212.98 
 04/01/2014  COR72      $732.35        $1,212.98
 04/01/2014  COR72    $ (732.35)       $1,212.98
 04/01/2014  COR72      $272.10        $1,212.98
 04/01/2014  COR73      $460.25        $1,212.98 
 04/01/2014  COS83    $2,239.20        $1,212.98
```

Sample Results:

```
 Pay End     Emp ID   Total Earnings   WC (Cap)     Exposure
 04/01/2014  CIA77    $1,858.80        $1,212.98    $1,212.98
 04/01/2014  COL23    $1,375.73        $1,212.98    $1,212.98
 04/01/2014  COM64      $285.20        $1,212.98      $285.20 
 04/01/2014  COR71    $2,821.72        $1,212.98    $1,212.98 
 04/01/2014  COR72      $732.35        $1,212.98        $0.00
 04/01/2014  COR72    $ (732.35)       $1,212.98        $0.00
 04/01/2014  COR72      $272.10        $1,212.98      $272.10
 04/01/2014  COR73      $460.25        $1,212.98      $460.25
 04/01/2014  COS83    $2,239.20        $1,212.98    $1,212.98
```

Is there a way to also just return the value on the last row? Ex COR72 has 3 entries on 4/1/2014 can the 1st and 2nd row be zero and the 3rd row have the value.

Comment: Please consider to reword your question - not clear

Comment: Your example is not very clear. If the `Total Earnings` for each COR72 record were 1, 2, and 3, would you want to return `3` (the last entry) or `6` (the sum of all COR72 records for that date)?

Comment: Sorry, I'd like it to return the sum of all COR72 records for that date.

Comment: Is your data sorted? For example, are all values for a employee id and date going to be grouped together?

Comment: The data is sorted by Pay End and then Emp ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is sorted by `Pay End` and `Emp ID`, you can fill down the following formula in the `Exposure` field (starting in `E2`).

```
=IF(B2=B3,0,SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$B$2:$B$10,B2,$A$2:$A$10,A2,$C$2:$C$10,"<"&D2)+SUMIFS($D$2:$D$10,$B$2:$B$10,B2,$A$2:$A$10,A2,$C$2:$C$10,">="&D2))
```

This formula works by checking if the employee ID below matches the employee ID in the current row. If so, a `0` is entered. If not, then the row is the last entry for that ID and date.

The cap value in column D is handled by using the sum of two `SUMIFS` functions: one to sum the appropriate values in column C where the value in C is less than the cap value in column D, and another to sum the appropriate values in D where the value in column C is greater than or equal to the value in D. This guarantees the right value is counted for each record.

Comment: I'll try that out this morning thank you for your efforts. Quick question why the use of $ at times and not others?

Comment: Excellll that formula worked out great.

Comment: I noticed on all the single row it works perfectly, but on the multiple rows the math isn't working out. I'm going to try to figure it out but your formula is great. Gave me some good insight.

Comment: Thanks again Excellll I've got something that's working for me based on your formula.   =MIN(IF(V2=V3,0,SUMIFS($AI$2:$AI$10829,$V$2:$V$10829,V2,$P$2:$P$10829,P2)),AJ2)